# Unable to move chatbubbles in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to build a bad client for chatgpt inside kivy as a project,i have implmented chatbubbles but they are both positioned next to eachother,i have consulted documentation to no avail,any fix?

here is my implementation

```
import requests
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

# Set size and color of window before app initialization
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'visible')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_height', '600')

Builder.load_string("""
<ChatBubble>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (40/255,116/255,166/255, 1) if root.role == "bot" else (0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1)  # Change color for bot messages
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [20, 20, 20, 20] if root.role == "bot" else [20, 20, 0, 20]  # Round corners for bot messages

    Label:
        text: root.text
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1) if root.role == "bot" else (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1)
        font_size: 16
        text_size: (self.width - 20, None)
        valign: "top"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1] + 20


<ChatInterface>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    history: history_rv
    input: input_text

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 70
        
        TextInput:
            id: input_text
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.send_message()
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0  # transparent background

        Button:
            text: "Send"
            on_press: root.send_message()

    RecycleView:
        id: history_rv
        data: [{"text": msg["content"], "role": msg["role"]} for msg in root.messages]
        viewclass: "ChatBubble"
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 10

""")

class ChatBubble(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()
    role = StringProperty()

class ChatInterface(BoxLayout):
    history = ObjectProperty()
    input = ObjectProperty()
    messages = []

    def send_message(self):
        message = self.input.text.strip()
        if not message:
            return

        payload = {
            "messages": self.messages + [{"role": "user", "content": message}]
        }
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

        completion_message = response.json()["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]

        self.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": message})

        self.history.data.append({"role": "user", "text": message})
        self.history.data.append({"role": "bot", "text": completion_message})
        self.input.text = ""

class ChatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChatInterface()
    
    #OPENAI CODE GOES HERE

if __name__ == "__main__":
ChatApp().run()
```

chatbubbles are misaligned and i cannot find any fix in the documentation,perhaps there is some fix involving a label although that is the most of my findings,hopefully a fix will be found

Comment: Could you post an image of what your code produces?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/HJV-MDH2aYpu

Comment: So, how do you want the output arranged?

Comment: Just gave one to the right and one to the left